# Mocha and socket.io timeout

Tags: socket.io, mocha.js

I'm just getting started trying to use Mocha with socket.io

I have a minimal test with an equally minimal server

When I invoke emit() from the test client, the test times out (even though I have put 'done()' in the callback)

It looks like the callback isn't getting called, even though the message is being received by the server - I don't see anything from the 'consolelog' in the callback of the emit function, so I assume the function isn't completing for some reason

I've trawled through various examples, but cant see what I'm missing (or done wrong)

Any help appreciated

**here's the test code**

```
const websocket_Server = require('./wsserver');
const http = require('http');
const io = require('socket.io-client');

describe('Websocket server tests', function(){
    let http_Server = undefined;
    let websocket_Client = undefined;

    before(function(done) {
        http_Server = http.createServer(() => console.log(" -/- "));
        http_Server.listen(7575, () => { console.log("Test: server listening on 7575"); });

        websocket_Server(http_Server);

        websocket_Client = io.connect('http://localhost:7575/', {
            'reconnection delay' : 0
            , 'reopen delay' : 0
            , 'force new connection' : true
        });
        
        websocket_Client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Client: connected...');
            done();
        });
        
        websocket_Client.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('Client: disconnected...');
        });
    });

    it('Test', function(done) {
        console.log("Client: Test");
        websocket_Client.emit('MSG', '', () =>{ console.log("Client: emit MSG"); done(); });
        console.log("Client: Test finish");
    });
})
```

---

**here's the server code**

---

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

function socketServer(serverToBind) {
    const io = socketIO(serverToBind);

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('WS_Server: Client Connected')
    
        socket.on('MSG', (msg) =>{
            console.log('WS_Server: MSG received');
            
            // pass data onto other processes........
        });
    });
}

module.exports = socketServer;
```

---

### **And here's the output**

```
Websocket server tests
Test: server listening on 7575
WS_Server: Client Connected
Client: connected...
Client: Test
Client: Test finish
WS_Server: MSG received
1) Test

0 passing (2s)
1 failing

1) Websocket server tests
   Test:
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if 
 returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\SVN-Development\WebSockets\minimal socket 
 test\wsserver.spec.js)
  at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
  at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out what I had wrong
I wrongly assumed the callback on the emit function was invoked when the function completed, but it's actually invoked by an acknowledgement from the server, which isn't being done in my code, hence the function doesn't complete
I've modified my code and all working as expected now